# CSS classes definitions

Tags: css

Haven't done any css for almost 15 years now and things do have changed a bit.
I was looking into the code bellow and I can't seem to make sense of some of the things

This is is original markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Pseudo Classes & Pseudo Elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>

        .dropdown-content a {
            display: none;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a {
            display: block;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Items</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">item 1</a>
            <a href="#">item 2</a>
            <a href="#">item 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

So,

Why affect all the 'a' here if it does not produce any effect on the outer 'a'?

```
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a {
            display: block;
        }
```

I can also seem to achieve the same result if I use just this:

```
    /* .dropdown-content a {
        display: none;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a {
        display: block;
    } */

    .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
            display: grid;
        }
```

Is there any problems with it?

I also can't seem to understand why this does not show the 3 links at all, I don't understand the why not setting the display property of the 'a' items would stop all the other 'a' from showing up.

```
    .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a{
            display: block;
        }
```

Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why affect all the 'a' here if it does not produce any effect on the outer 'a'?
>
> ```
>   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a {
>       display: block;
>  }
> ```

There is no effect on outer `a` tag as intended. Because the style is being applied to only those `a` tags which are inside an element with `dropdown-content` which is in turn inside an element having class `dropdown` in hover state.

It is according to css combinators : refer [CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#descendant_combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#descendant_combinator)

---

> ```
> .dropdown-content {
>        display: none;
>   }
>
>   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
>      display: grid;
> }
> ```
>
> Is there any problems with it?

since there are no elements other than `a` inside `dropdown-content`, hiding all the elements inside that container or hiding that container itself feels same.

---

> I also can't seem to understand why this does not show the 3 links at all, I don't understand the why not setting the display property of the 'a' items would stop all the other 'a' from showing up.
>
> ```
>  .dropdown-content {
>        display: none;
>  }
>
>   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a{
>      display: block;
> }
> ```

This is only changing the display property of the children i.e anchor tags, but the container `dropdown-content` has still `display:none` (even in hover state of `dropdown`). So anchor tags will not be shown unless the display property of  their container `dropdown-content` is changed to proper value other than `none`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the 'a'-elements, because you have set `display: none;` to it.
In the original markup

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
}
```

makes that when you hover above `.dropdown` the 'a's are set to `display: block;` and shown.